# Memory for pointer address sporadically altered pre and post function return

Tags: c++, arrays, eigen

Memory at specified address is not identical pre and post function return and the basis for this behavior is unclear.  Invoking the function multiple times will sporadically result in the correct result; however, the vast proportion of time, the memory has been altered.

Need to reliably return a simple C/C++ float array (as opposed to a std::vector/array, etc.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace Eigen;

float* derive_inverse(float* wasm_memory_address, int size) {

  MatrixXf matrix_from_memory = Map<Matrix<float, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor> >(wasm_memory_address, size, size);

  std::cout << '\n';
  std::cout << "Matrix" << '\n';
  std::cout << matrix_from_memory << '\n' << '\n';

  MatrixXf inverse = matrix_from_memory.inverse();

  std::cout << "Inverse" << '\n';
  std::cout << inverse << '\n' << '\n';

  float* vc = inverse.data();

  std::cout << "inverse address prior to return: " << vc << '\t' << '\n';
  std::cout << "first few entries (column major order):" << '\n';
  std::cout << vc[0] << '\t' << vc[1] << '\t' << vc[2] << '\n' << '\n';

  return vc;
}

int main() {

  float numbers[25] = { 1, 8, -9, 7, 5, 0, 1, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, -5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1};
  float* inverse = derive_inverse(&numbers[0], 5);

  std::cout << "inverse address following return: " << inverse << '\t' << '\n';
  std::cout << "first few entries (column major order):" << '\n';
  std::cout << inverse[0] << '\t' << inverse[1] << '\t' << inverse[2] << '\n' << '\n';

  std::cout << "entire inverse matrix following return:" << '\n';
   for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
     for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
       int index = row * 5 + col;
       std::cout << inverse[row * 5 + col] << '\t';
     }
     std::cout << '\n';
   }
   std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Example of successive invocations resulting in erroneous and correct results:

```
$ ./foo

Matrix
 1  8 -9  7  5
 0  1  0  4  4
 0  0  1  2  5
 0  0  0  1 -5
 0  0  0  0  1

Inverse
  1  -8   9   7  17
  0   1   0  -4 -24
  0   0   1  -2 -15
  0   0   0   1   5
  0   0   0   0   1

inverse address prior to return: 0x7ff5c8500ba0 
first few entries (column major order):
1   0   0

inverse address following return: 0x7ff5c8500ba0    
first few entries (column major order):
0   -3.68935e+19    0

entire inverse matrix following return:
0   -8  9   7   17  
-3.68935e+19    1   0   -4  -24 
0   0   1   -2  -15 
-3.68935e+19    0   0   1   5   
2.52234e-44 0   0   0   1   

$ ./foo

Matrix
 1  8 -9  7  5
 0  1  0  4  4
 0  0  1  2  5
 0  0  0  1 -5
 0  0  0  0  1

Inverse
  1  -8   9   7  17
  0   1   0  -4 -24
  0   0   1  -2 -15
  0   0   0   1   5
  0   0   0   0   1

inverse address prior to return: 0x7f96afd000a0 
first few entries (column major order):
1   0   0

inverse address following return: 0x7f96afd000a0    
first few entries (column major order):
1   0   0

entire inverse matrix following return:
1   -8  9   7   17  
0   1   0   -4  -24 
0   0   1   -2  -15 
0   0   0   1   5   
0   0   0   0   1
```

Comment: *Need to reliably return a simple C/C++ float array* This is not possible.  Copy it into a vector and return that.

Comment: `inverse` has automatic storage duration. The object is destroyed after the function returns (together with its data). The pointer becomes invalid.

Answer (score 3):

Your function returns a pointer to the internal data of an object that does not live once the function returns. Dereferencing that pointer in the calling function causes undefined behavior.

```
float* vc = inverse.data();   // inverse is not alive after the function returns.

...


return vc;  // The returned pointer becomes a dangling pointer once the function returns.
```

One way to address that would be to return an object instead of a pointer to internal data.

```
MatrixXf derive_inverse(float* wasm_memory_address, int size) {
   ...

   return inverse;
}
```

Comment: Thank you (all).  This is obvious in hindsight but appreciate the group's patience